# Unable to add an installed MS Teams App as a Tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm currently working on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio) tutorial and came up to the the section 'Configure the app tab'. However, instead of being able to choose a Tab to display, I am only shown a preview of the opening Tab with the save option greyed out. Bot-Communication through the installed App also fails ('unable to reach the App'), which suggests it's a client-based problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate questions in here, but let's start with the first, about the Tab. It's important to understand the difference between "personal"/"static" tabs, and "shared"/"configurable" tabs. Personal tabs appear if you install the app into your own account direclty (e.g. by going via the "App" option on the left menu", whereas "shared" tabs are ones you add to a group chat or channel. These "shared" tabs don't add -directly- to the chat/channel, they first need to show a "configuration" popup where users can be shown any options you need to configure the final tab (see for instance the "SharePoint" option when you add a new tab to an existing channel.

In contrast, "personal" tabs just add the tab directly. If you want to just see your tab in action directly, in "personal" mode, then just use the "Add" button direclty in App Studio - don't select the dropdown to add it to a channel/chat - you'll need to add a "config" screen first. In addition, your config screen needs to tell Teams that you're done with the config (via a javascript command), which then enables the Save button

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it allowed me to troubleshoot the issue, which was the URL for the configuration page being wrong. I'm afraid though I don't understand the purpose of the configuration tab to full extend yet. Is the configuraton Tab equal to the Tab with team scope, from which there can only be one per app according to the MS docs? And am I even obligated to implement it, if my App is aimed for personal use only (such as App-Studio, which is not visible through the tab-option, but through the 'add app' menu only)?

Comment: glad to help. So simple answer is "yes", for a "shared" tab, you definitely need a config page - it gives you the chance to allow the user to set any settings that might make sense for your app. As an example, say I've got an app where in some channels any user should have read/write, but in others only a team owner can modify the tab content - the config page allows whoever is adding the tab to set that, in this particular channel, x rule must apply, vs. y rule in another

Comment: Incidentally, that's why the are called "Configurable" tabs. That said, if you really have NO config to set, you basically just set `settings.setValidityState(true)` straight away in your code, and the "save" button will become enabled within a moment or two

Comment: With regards your "bot" issue, I'd like to suggest the following - pull it out of the above (i.e. edit your original question) and put it into a separate post, so that people can see it more specifically. When you do, please note where the bot is hosted (i.e. is it local machine, running ngrok?).

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you trying to add a [configurable tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page)? Please take a look at the sample [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-sample-line-of-business-apps-csharp/blob/master/Professional%20Services/LeaveBot/Views/Home/Configure.cshtml) on how your configuration page should look like. You will need to have `settings.setValidityState(true)` to enable the save button.
2. Bot communication fails with "Unable to reach app"- Could you please add more details on this issue? Did you add the Bot id and password in the config file? Does your app hit when you send a message to the Bot?

Comment: 1. The configuring issue has been resolved, I was refering to the wrong page in the confirguration tab page.

Comment: 2. When I install the app and open the chat in the respective app's personal tab, @ing the bot and sending messages yields no response despite having him registered with MS and updating the application.json.

Comment: You don't have to @mention the bot if you are talking to it in 1:1 scope. Did you set the endpoint for your Bot correctly? Does your debugger hit when you send a message to Bot?

Comment: After some time I fixed the "unable to reach app" issue by registering uthe the bot with Azure, however I am still ot able to receive messages. I openend a seperate [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005919/microsoft-bot-is-not-responding-in-either-teams-nor-the-bot-emulator) for that now.