# Microsoft Bot is not responding in either Teams nor the Bot Emulator

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have:

- The corresponding Web-App running on localhost.
- An open channel for MS Teams active within the Bot Framework, which displays 'running' all the time (no issues).
- downloaded a VS19 project from git with a few pre-set bot-commands.

However, when I host the app via ngrok and try to contact the bot via teams the dropdown menu with the commands is diplayed, but the the bot replies to none of them.
When using the Bot Emulator, it also does not react to any messages (see below).

```
You said:
hello

Restart conversation from here
You said:
help

Restart conversation from here
Connectivity Status: Connected
Suggested Actions Container: Is empty

[10:03:51]Connecting to bot on https://localhost:3979/api/messages
[10:03:51]Emulator listening on http://[::]:58187
[10:03:52]-> conversationUpdate
[10:03:52]ngrok listening on https://67fe6eb30077.ngrok.io
[10:03:52]ngrok traffic inspector:http://127.0.0.1:4040
[10:03:52]Will bypass ngrok for local addresses
[10:03:52]POST400directline/conversations/<conversationId>/activities
[10:03:58]-> message hello
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222023/discussion-on-question-by-beltway-microsoft-bot-is-not-responding-in-either-team).

Answer (score 1):

Since i was unable to resolve the issue I started the registration process over, this times with our tenants account. It didn't change very much except for causing an AADSTS700016-Error server side. After some research I stumbled accross [this](http://thewindowsupdate.com/2019/08/19/how-to-create-an-app-registration-in-azure-ad-for-a-bot-solution/) article, which explains the issue but also shows the solution, namely setting "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" in the registration manifest. This option was not available for my app for some reason so I set it to "signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs", which resolved the issue for now.